# Disproving complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

I think I lack intution when dealing with disproving holomorphicity of functions like:

> a) $f(z) = \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}$
>   b) $f(z) = \left \{ \begin{array} .\frac{z^5}{\lvert z^4 \rvert} &z\neq 0\\0 & z=0 \end{array} \right . $

For a), one way to prove it is that we have constant modulus, therefore $f$ can't be holomorphic since in that case it would be constant (using the Open Mapping Theorem or the Cauchy Riemann equations). Is there an alternative way of proving this conveniently?

For b), I am unsure, since we don't have constant modulus. We can write $z = |z|e^{i \varphi}$ using polar coordinates and get $$f(z) = \left \{ \begin{array} . \lvert z \rvert e^{5i \varphi} &z\neq 0\\0 & z=0 \end{array} \right .$$ 
This to me looks similar like the identity, besides the $5$ in the exponent. How do I prove this one isn't holomorphic (at $z=0$)?

Comment: Can you use identity theorem?

Comment: For (a), $f$ is not even defined at $z=0$. You might want to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, it is often useful to simply go back to the definition. A function is complex differentiable if for all $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ has a limit when $z \to z_0$.

Here there is clearly a problem at $z_0 = 0$. So let's try to compute $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)/z$.

For a), $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)/z = (z/|z|)/z = 1/|z|$ which does not converge to anything as $t \to 0$. So the limit doesn't exist.

For b), it's a bit more subtle. A useful property in complex analysis is that if a limit exists, then it must be the same limit along all path leading to the point $z_0$. Let's try to compute the limit along a horizontal vertical line, i.e. with $z = t$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \to 0$ (distinguishing the two cases $t>0$ and $t<0$).

For the first one, $f(t) = t^5/|t|^4$. If $t > 0$, this gives $f(t) = t$ and so $f(t)/t = 1$ and the limit is $1$. But if $t < 0$, then $f(t) = -t$ and $f(t)/t = -1$ and the limit is $-1$. But to be complex differentiable, the limit should have been the same, a contradiction. So the function is not complex differentiable.

Comment: Really good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Additional question: for a), is the function holomorphic on the rest of $\mathbb C $ besides $z = 0$?

Comment: @lappen68 No, it is not. Its modulus is constant, that's not possible for holomorphic functions.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint**
Compute $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(it)}{it}\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)}{t}$$

Comment: downvoter, explain ??

Comment: A one-line hint is pointless, and since there's no need to compute $f(it)/it$ I can only assume that you didn't even try to do the computations yourself. Hence, downvote. Your peremptory tone in asking for an explanation for the downvote only comforts me in my decision.